# Как вырезать строку их url адреса?

Tags: php

У нас имеется url

```
http://www.video.com/tube/videos/429000/something.html
```

Как мне вырезать отсюда число 429000?

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr=split('/',$ваша строка);
```

//$arr[5]=429000

Answer (score 2):

Наверное как-то так:

```
$url = "http://www.video.com/tube/videos/429000/something.html";
if (preg_match("|/videos/(\d+)/|", $url, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
}
```

Comment: А как заменить потом из текста этот урл на ифрейм код?

Comment: Не понял задачу. Для чего это нужно - опишите по-подробнее